# OpenRead url give exception: Could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, url, stream

```
try
{    
    string url = "jquery.org/resources/members/ibm.png";
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        using (Stream stream = client.OpenRead(url))
        {
           //some login here
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  return false;
}
```

exception: "**Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\jquery.org\resources\members\ibm.png'.**"

url is not contain "http://" or "https://" and it found in the disc C, how I can to execute OpenRead stream from this url?

Comment: What about simply adding `http://` if your input-url doesn't start with this scheme?

Comment: @khlr I can be http:// or https://, how know which is correct

Comment: @khlr worked! thanks for help, put your comment into answer and I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the scheme `"http://"` first. In your example a request `http://jquery.org/resources/members/ibm.png` will receive a *301 Moved Permanently*.

`WebClient` should automatically follow the Location-header within the response and make another to `https://jquery.org/resources/members/ibm.png`.

Additionally you could add some error handling to your code and do another request manually with scheme `https://` if a prior http-request didn't succeed and there was no Location-header in the response.